# How to Unit test 2 consecutive calls to the same method with different parameter types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Working with C# .NetFrameWork 4.7, Moq 1.4

I'm testing a method that makes 2 interface calls.  The interface method takes in 1 parameter, and that parameter is an interface as well.  Having a hard time testing this, Moq is throwing casting errors.

2 consecutive calls with the following signiture:

```
InterfaceUnderTest.MethodUnderTest(IEnumerable<IParamInterface>)
```

The complete code example can be found here on github: https://github.com/JayZhang727/UnitTestingInterfaceParams

Following is the basic structure:

interfaces and implementations being imported that I can not change:

```
public interface IWorkInterface
{
    string DoWork(IEnumerable<IParamInterface> para);
}

public interface IParamInterface
{
    IParamDataInterface GetParamData();
}

public interface IParamDataInterface
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ParamClass<T> : IParamInterface where T : IParamDataInterface
{
    public T ParamData { get; set; }

    public ParamClass()
    {

    }

    public ParamClass(T para)
    {
        this.ParamData = para;
    }

    public IParamDataInterface GetParamData()
    {
        return ParamData;
    }
}

public class ParamClassA : IParamDataInterface
{
    public ParamClassA()
    {
        this.Id = "Id";
        this.ParamClassAVar = 123;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int ParamClassAVar { get; set; }

}

public class ParamClassB : IParamDataInterface
{
    public ParamClassB()
    {
        this.Id = "Id";
        this.ParamClassBVar = "not 123";
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string ParamClassBVar { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the class under test:

```
public ClassUnderTest(IWorkInterface workInt)
{
    this.WorkClient = workInt;
}

public IWorkInterface WorkClient { get; set; }

public string MethodUnderTest()
{
    var result = string.Empty;

    //Class A is an implementation of IParamDataInterface
    var a = new ParamClassA();
    var theParamA = new ParamClass<ParamClassA>(a);
    var listA = new List<IParamInterface>();
    listA.Add(theParamA);

    result = WorkClient.DoWork(listA);

    //Class B is also an implementation of IParamDataInterface
    var b = new ParamClassB();
    var theParamB = new ParamClass<ParamClassB>(b);
    var listB = new List<IParamInterface>();
    listB.Add(theParamB);

    result = result + WorkClient.DoWork(listB);

    return result;
}
```

Here is the test calls that I tried:

```
private Mock<IWorkInterface> mockClient;

[TestMethod()]
public void DoWorkTest()
{
    mockClient = new Mock<IWorkInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var target = new ClassUnderTest(mockClient.Object);

    var mockSquence = new MockSequence();

    mockClient.InSequence(mockSquence).Setup(ec => ec.DoWork(It.Is<List<IParamInterface>>(el => ((ParamClassA)((ParamClass<ParamClassA>)el[0]).GetParamData()).ParamClassAVar == 123))).Returns("123");

    mockClient.InSequence(mockSquence).Setup(ec => ec.DoWork(It.Is<List<IParamInterface>>(el => ((ParamClassB)((ParamClass<ParamClassB>)el[0]).GetParamData()).ParamClassBVar == "not 123"))).Returns("not 123");

    //act
    target.MethodUnderTest();


    //assert
    mockClient.VerifyAll();
}
```

I get errors about can not cast from Class A to Class B:

```
Message: Test method ClassUnderTesting.UnitTests.ClassUnderTestingTests.DoWorkTest threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ClassUnderTesting.ParamClass`1[ClassUnderTesting.ParamClassA]' to type 'ClassUnderTesting.ParamClass`1[ClassUnderTesting.ParamClassB]'.
```

It seems that Moq is not doing it in sequence and for some reason, the second setup is trumping the first setup and sequence doesn't seem to help. Anyone know how I should setup and test these 2 calls?

Comment: Just a side note, Moq is not a testing framework. NUnit, xUnit, those are testing framework. Moq is a Mocking framework that'll help you in your testing job :)

Comment: corrected the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this without a sequence. Just setup your expectations so that when DoWork is called with `ParamClassA` it returns "123", and when it's called with `ParamClassB` it returns "not 123".

Note that the first expectation will not crash if it is not given `ParamClassA`: it simply won't match (and likewise the second and `ParamClassB`).

```
mockClient
    .Setup(ec => ec.DoWork(
        It.Is<List<IParamInterface>>(el => el[0] is ParamClass<ParamClassA> && ((ParamClass<ParamClassA>)el[0]).ParamData.ParamClassAVar == 123)
    ))
    .Returns("123");

mockClient
    .Setup(ec => ec.DoWork(
        It.Is<List<IParamInterface>>(el => el[0] is ParamClass<ParamClassB> && ((ParamClass<ParamClassB>)el[0]).ParamData.ParamClassBVar == "not 123")
    ))
    .Returns("not 123");
```

Comment: that does not seem to compile when I pasted it in, get the error: "an expression tree may not contain an "is" pattern-matching operator".  I have also tried with out using the sequence, and it still throws the same casting errors as I had originally.

Comment: @DotNetNewbie1024 edited my answer. Yes, you will get exceptions with your code, because you calls to `Setup` *cast* the argument to the type you expect. You need to change it to *check if* the argument has the type you expected.

Comment: now I get the error: "an expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator".  after removing the ? from the expression, I get a null exception error running the code.  It seems the "as" operator doesn't cast it correct when running the code.

Comment: @DotNetNewbie1024 bleh, updated again. The NullReferenceException is expected: `as` returns `null` if the cast fails (and it will fail, because the cast to `ParamClassB` will fail when the method is actually passed `ParamClassA`). That is why I used the null-propagating operator.

Comment: This works great.  I've edited your reply with corrections on some typos, marking it as the answer.  Thank you!